# DocuSign Recommended Parsing of DateSigned Tab Value

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm retrieving a `DateSigned` tab from the Form Data of an envelope. The string that is returned is formatted like:

```
5/29/2018 | 1:21:42 PM PDT
```

The standard `DateTime.TryParse` and `DateTimeOffset.TryParse` fails while trying to parse this string. **Does DocuSign have a recommended way to parse strings of this format?** Preferably, I'd like to parse the string to a DateTimeOffset (versus DateTime).

Comment: is there a requirement to have DateSigned field with timestamp on the document, are you fine if you have only date without timestamp on the document?

Comment: I will likely need to retrieve the date and time from the DateSigned tab. What are the options?

Comment: In which coding language you are parsing it?

Comment: Sorry, I'll be parsing it in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *almost* do this using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx).  The problem is that there is no custom format string that understand the time-zone abbreviation.

If you rip off the last 4 characters that store the time zone (including the space), you can parse it using the following code.

```
var dateString = "5/29/2018 | 1:21:42 PM"; // Time-zone stripped out
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString,
                           "M/d/yyyy | h:m:s tt",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out var theDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine(theDate);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse date");
}
```

In order to apply the time-zone, you will have to manually figure out the offset from UTC by reading the abbreviation, and looking it up [somehow](https://mj1856.github.io/TimeZoneNames/).

Comment: This post, in combination with the link, provided me with enough information to solve the issue I was having. Thanks!